# Cannot get badge to line up with link in navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble figuring out how to get a badge next to a link in my navbar and have it line up correctly.

```
<ul class="nav">
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Link</a><span class="badge badge-important">4</span></li>
```

Here is a JSFiddle example of my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/pHRc9/3/

Answer (score 5):

Try putting the close of the a href outside of the span close.

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link <span class="badge badge-important">4</span></a></li>
```

**Updated Answer**

You didn't specify that in your question.  Using the code you have already existing, and placing this css worked okay for me.

```
a {
    float:left !important;
}
span {
    float: left !important;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: That does work however, i don't really want the badge to be part of the link

Comment: Edited answer.  I believe this should work; of course, you'd want to more specifically reference the anchor and span tag.

Comment: yes looking at the bootstrap css, they are only specifying styles for a tags inside the nav, and nothing else. Hence why adding a span outside the 'a' tag does not look right.

Comment: If this has solved your question, please feel free to mark it as solved.  If it hasn't and you done something else to solve it, feel free to answer your own question with your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you would want the badge outside the link as the entire link becomes a block.
The best way to have the badges to the right is similar to [lostintranslation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14907138/793558)'s answer, but instead of using `.badge-important` use `.pull-right`.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is to place the badges as list elements:

```
  %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
    %li.navbar-text
      %span.badge boo
    %li.navbar-text
      %span.label.label-primary foo
```

That seems to work nice for me.